# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el valor de un checkbox en una SessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero guardar el valor de un checkbox (ya sea on/true u off/false) en una variable SessionStorage.

Este es el checkbox a guardar:

```
 <label class="switch pull-right">
            <input name="SeleccionarTodos" type="checkbox" id="SeleccionarTodos" onclick="checkAll()" />
            <span class="slider round vista"></span>
</label>
```

Yo lo pensé así para setearlo, con nombre "Seleccionar Todos".

```
let selectAll = $(('#SeleccionarTodos').checked);

sessionStorage.setItem("SeleccionarTodos", selectAll);
```

Y para cuando vuelva a la vista me lo traigo así:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#SeleccionarTodos').checked = sessionStorage.getItem("SeleccionarTodos"); 
}
```

Obviamente algo estoy haciendo mal y por eso no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estás usando el código correcto para obtener el estado del `checkbox`.

Tú puedes escuchar el evento `change` de ese elemento, haciendo que su estado se guarde en `sessionStorage` con algo como esto:

```
  var checkStatus = $(this).prop('checked');
```

`$(this)`, dentro del evento `change` hará referencia al checkbox, y con `prop('checked')` obtienes el estado del elemento (`true` si está chequeado, o `false` si no lo está).

La función quedaría así:

```
/*
    Escucha los cambios en el checkbox
  */

$('#SeleccionarTodos').on('change', function() {
  var checkStatus = $(this).prop('checked');
  console.log(checkStatus);
  sessionStorage.setItem("SeleccionarTodos", checkStatus);
});
```

Luego, allí donde necesites obtener el valor que está guardado en `sessionStorage` haces esto:

```
  var sessionStatus = sessionStorage.getItem("SeleccionarTodos");
```

Y tendras en `sessionStatus` el valor que esté almacenado.

#### Demo

<kbd>[**VER DEMO JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/bvz13oyr/6/)</kbd>.

Puedes probar a marcar/desmarcar el elemento y con el botón podrás ver qué valor hay guardado en `sessionStorage`.

Comment: eh intentado de esa manera, cuando navego en las vistas el valor me lo pasa bien, pero aunque el estado sea false me pone el checkbox en true, osea el valor es false pero el usuario lo ve como en true, no sé si me explico

Comment: @BilbitBolson yo he querido mostrarte cómo se guarda o se saca de `sessionStorage` y he indicado la forma correcta de extraer el estado del checkbox (true o false). Si hay algún otro problema será en la lógica de tu programa. De todos modos, cualquier otra incidencia que surja, si no puedes resolverla, no dudes en abrir una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Si, era un problema mío en la lógica el cual ya pude resolver, te agradezco la paciencia y tu tiempo para contestarme mis dudas, te pido disculpas.

Comment: No hay ningún problema ni nada que disculpar @BilbitBolson, me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.